# Do I need a node server with a REST API react app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, crud

I'm making a CRUD web application with react. I tried using node and mongodb to create a REST API.

The problem is I don't need the server to send me any html pages. I want all the views to be rendered by react and all the data to be available in json format stored in some urls. When I make a post request, I don't want to use res.send() or res.redirect('/') in node; I want react to update the data that has just been posted. In this case, do I even need a server?

Another thing is when I deploy my app, I need to set up a database somewhere. [mLab](https://docs.mlab.com/data-api/), for one, can be used as a database and a REST API at the same time. It has urls and I can fetch the data in react. Is it fine to use mlab API for a simple app production?

Am I doing things wrongly?

Comment: Yes you do need a server - any database connections should happen only on the server - and the front end (or your React application) is only allowed access to the API that handles the database CRUD

Comment: If you use MLab like service, you are still using a server - so basically meeting the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> I want all the views to be rendered by react and all the data to be available in json format stored in some urls.

You just said in your question that you want to store your data server-side... which naturally, requires a server.

> When I make a post request, I don't want to use res.send() or res.redirect('/') in node; I want react to update the data that has just been posted. In this case, do I even need a server?

Well, yes, otherwise there's no point in making a request at all.

> mlab, for one, can be used as a database and a REST API at the same time. It has urls and I can fetch the data in react. Is it fine to use mlab API for a simple app production?

I don't know what MLab is, but that's your server... so yes.

It's unclear what you're actually trying to do, so let me just break it down like this:

- If your data is static, lives on the client, or no data is required, then you don't need an application server.  A static web server (or equivalent, such as CDN hosting) is sufficient.
- If your data is to be shared with others, stored in a central location, acted upon while clients are offline, then you need an application server of some sort.

Comment: But I want the data to be available in react for rendering the views, in that case, I will use the fetch API in react, aren't the server codes like app.get(...), app.post(...) redundant then? If I rely on the node server to deal with the requests instead, how can I get back the data in react without reloading the page? I'm confused what the node server is doing for me because it seems that I can make requests in react itself.

Comment: @lmathl Yes, if you were simply proxying the data server-side, then that was redundant.  You can just make those requests client-side.

Comment: @Matth3w I did, actually.  The point I was trying to make is that the fact that it's MLab (vs. something else) is irrelevant.  I find it better to explain *why* and *how to choose* the tradeoffs here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking
*you can do this by use onchange method or onclick method I mean if you have used any drop-down list or any button then u can get that data by not loading the page*

**just u need to call one more fetch method in that same page and save data JSON data in that same variable so it will show that on in web page without loading the page**

Answer (score 0):

Just make node server with connection to dB. All data displaying handle on client by react. To make a requests use some library like axios. And on the server just reply to those requests. So there would be no need for reloading page.